# Move amount vertices with Python

Tags: python

let me explain it again, also with an image:-) I have 4 points in 3d space (vertices in the 3d viewport) and I know the direction-vector d (normalized) of the plane they are building.

[image: Vertices and direction vector of the face]

Now I want to calculate the amount of the length of the vector (positive or negative) when I move the mouse along the direction d for extruding these vertices - so that I can re-implement an extrude operation and the mouse cursor is visually in sync.

This is what blender does when moving vertices, edges or faces with a constraint to a certain direction.

Any ideas or Python code?

Thx in advance

Comment: Can find the plane projected into the view from the mouse. The method we spoke of before gives the 3d vector into the view from mouse location. Arbitrarily choose viewport up as another vector on the plane. (just add some to mouse Y coord and convert to 3d) The 3d mouse coordinate and the vector which is the cross product of the view vector and up defines the plane.  Then use intersect line with plane to project vector d onto said plane.  Could alternatively define a plane with normal d such that mouse point is on it and find the intersection.

Comment: Ok thx, let me try to sum it up, also with Python code.

1. region_2d_to_vector_3d gives me the vector into the view from 2d mouse position. 
2. I need a viewport vector up, havent understood how to get this. Also mouse pos 2d with some more y and pass to region_2d_to_vector_3d?
3. The 3d mouse coordinate, cross product... not sure how to define a plane with it
4. Use intersect_line_plane, but what are the parameters? 1 and 2, first point and last point of the first line, which one? a point on the plane, ok mouse coord 3d, direction of the plane: cross product?

Comment: import and crunch `mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane(` into python console.  A plane is defined by a  point on plane and its normal. Because view and up are on the plane, the cross product gives us the normal to the plane with those two vectors (unless they are ||'el.

Comment: Ok, and intersect_line_plane returns a vector3, but what I need is the amount with that I can extrude. I really try to understand it but Im afraid I need more knowledge:-)

Comment: The result p is where d hits the plane.  If d originates at face center then extrude the face `(p - face.center).length * d`

Comment: I begin to understand:-)

1. I build a plane in the viewport with the 2d mouse positions as input. 
2. Try to intersect d with the plane to calculate the length. Multiply it with d to get a vector3 that I can add to the vertices?

Only thing I do not understand is what is the first and last point of the line, the first two parameters of intersect_line_with plane?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104176/discussion-between-jayanam-and-batfinger).